# DX Rotate 2D image

Tags: c++, math, directx-11

Ive found some things for drawing any image using DX11, so i need rotate this image around center of this image, but my math is bad :).

```
    void UpdateBuffers(int positionX, int positionY)
{
    if((positionX == m_previousPosX) && (positionY == m_previousPosY))
        return;

    m_previousPosX = positionX;
    m_previousPosY = positionY;

    float left = (float)((m_screenWidth / 2) * -1) + (float)positionX;
    float right = left + (float)m_bitmapWidth;
    float top = (float)(m_screenHeight / 2) - (float)positionY;
    float bottom = top - (float)m_bitmapHeight;

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    HRESULT result = m_render->m_pImmediateContext->Map(m_vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if(FAILED(result))
        return;

    Vertex *verticesPtr = (Vertex*)mappedResource.pData;

    verticesPtr[0].pos = XMFLOAT3(left, top, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[0].tex = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    verticesPtr[1].pos = XMFLOAT3(right, bottom, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[1].tex = XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    verticesPtr[2].pos = XMFLOAT3(left, bottom, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[2].tex = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f);

    verticesPtr[3].pos = XMFLOAT3(left, top, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[3].tex = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    verticesPtr[4].pos = XMFLOAT3(right, top, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[4].tex = XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    verticesPtr[5].pos = XMFLOAT3(right, bottom, 0.0f);
    verticesPtr[5].tex = XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    m_render->m_pImmediateContext->Unmap(m_vertexBuffer, 0);
}
```

As i understand im need 4 points for do this, but point struct should contains x and y axises, and this function have basiaclly x,y,w,h only and im bit confused with this. Mb somebody can help me.

Comment: You don't provide any details about your vertex shader or any constants it's using so it's difficult to help you. That said, you could just make use of ``SpriteBatch`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) which is optimized for exactly this kind of 2D drawing.

Comment: Ah, its not problem show vertex struct.
struct Vertex
{
 XMFLOAT3 pos;
 XMFLOAT2 tex;
};
Anyways if you need more info tell me.

Comment: There are many ways to get this wrong, and you aren't showing your HLSL shader or the constants.

Comment: Its all not secret cause i got this example in web.
https://pastebin.com/SsLZsNGc

UpdateBuffers in topic here. I include all shaders plus how this setups and inits